# Количество чисел в списке кратных трем

Tags: lisp

Находит просто количество чисел кратных трем, как сделать, чтобы если ввведен символ, то его пропускало? Проверка на numberp, но куда ее вставить? Куда ни вставлю, не работает. Код, который я теперь запускаю:

```
(defun cn (w n)
  (count-if #'numberp(lambda (a) (zerop (mod a n))) w))
```

Вызываю предыдущую функцию:

```
(cn '(3 9 1) 3)
```

Получаю:

```
2
```

А нужно вызывать так:

```
(cn '(3 9 d dd)3)
```

И видеть в результате:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

В формулировке Вашего вопроса я заметил одну неточность. Вы утверждаете, что Ваша функция должна проверять элементы списка на чётность трём, однако в примерах вызова заметно, что в принципе в качестве делителя может быть использовано любое число. Следовательно стоит учитывать, что функция помимо списка должна принимать ещё и число, кратность которому будет проверяться. Теперь давайте выясним, куда же стоит запихнуть проверку функцией `numberp`. Я предлагаю добавить дополнительную проверку с помощью `if` и на её основании далее проверять текущий элемент списка на чётность или сразу возвращать nil как знак того, что символы не могу быть кратны числам. В итоге получим что-то наподобие этого:

```
(defun cn (w n) (count-if (lambda (a) (if (numberp a) (zerop (mod a n)) nil)) w))
```

И теперь при вызове:

```
(cn '(3 9 d dd) 3)
```

Мы действительно получим:

```
2
```